# Writing large scripts in Impala

Tags: impala

I have to translate long Teradata scripts (10,000 lines long) into Impala. I never done this before with Impala.

The tools I’ve got to work with are impala shell or hue.

I’ve not seen an example of Impala code that’s more than 50 lines long either in impala shell or hue. Can someone point me to an example of impala script in either impala shell or hue that's *at least* 500 lines long?

*I can handle the syntax change*,I  don’t need advice on that. I’m looking for gotchas or traps in writing long code into these tools.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an external table with a source data to your file (as it's shown in [Impala tutorial](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_tutorial.html#tutorial_csv_setup)).

> ```
> -- The EXTERNAL clause means the data is located outside the central location
> -- for Impala data files and is preserved when the associated Impala table is dropped.
> -- We expect the data to already exist in the directory specified by the LOCATION clause.
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tab1
> (
>    id INT,
>    col_1 BOOLEAN,
>    col_2 DOUBLE,
>    col_3 TIMESTAMP
> )
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
> LOCATION '/user/cloudera/sample_data/tab1';
> ```

Then you can easily move your data whenever you want using `INSERT` construction.

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM tab1;
```

Comment: Does not answer my question. How do you develop very long scripts in impala shell or hue?

Comment: @Tired_Eyes What do you want to see in the answer?
I showed how you could represent your data in Impala, when you have an SQL table you can load your data to another storage with desired modification if needed.

Comment: What do you mean 'very long scripts', insert with 500 rows? With the approach above you don't need to do this. You create one table with storage of your file and you can select your data directly from your file. Then you create another table with the storage, for example, in Kudu. After it, you can load your data from your file to Kudo with Insert expression.

Comment: My Teradata code builds models of various types . Each script is over 10,000 programming lines long. They consist of many working tables, merge statements, delete statements etc. How does one develop an equivalent script using impala shell or hue? They seem to be only good form small scripts (a few tables , a few merge statements etc). I can't possibly see how you could manage to edit very long scripts in such tools. Is there some sort of trick to it?